# How to integrate Fundus camera in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have to integrate Fundus camera in android project to capture retina image. means 1 external camera is need to attach to smartphone via USB.

I have not get any solution for this problem

Comment: I am try to create app like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7tM1XnR5lk